# Boolean Algebra, prime implicants, karnaugh map

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, optimization, boolean-algebra, binary-operations

**This is the link to the question with my answer:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAXU7.jpg

I'm not sure if I identified the prime implicants and essential prime implicants correctly.

I need to know if my answer is correct, that is there are: **6** prime implicants, and **5** essential prime implicants.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one prime implicant, and as a consequence incorrectly declared one of the primes you found essential.

Comment: Is the missing prime implicant $\bar z$yw?  I'm not sure which prime implicant I'm missing?

Comment: It's $w\bar{z}$.

Comment: Ok, but is w$\bar z$ not covered by the other implicants indicated on the map?  Both the bottom right corner '1' and the '1' above it have largest power of two groupings - so why is w$\bar z$ needed?

Comment: @CoryCrowley Whether it exists is a different question of whether it is needed.  It is a maximal power-of-2 region, so it is a prime implicant.

Comment: An implicant like $w\bar{z}$ is sometimes called *inessential* prime.  In general, inessential primes cannot be dismissed if you are looking for a minimum cost cover.

Comment: I now understand!  Thank you all for the help.  I've marked the question as resolved.  I thought that because the 1s in the w$\bar z$ grouping were already covered by 'largest power of 2' groupings, I did not need to include w$\bar z$.  

So my understanding now is: prime implicants must be **all** largest power of 2 groupings for each '1' in the karnaugh map.